# exclude css file and image on url rewriting in php

Tags: php, url-rewriting

i have problem in loading css file and image file while using url rewriting with this rules :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^showProject-([^/]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ showProject.php?id=$2
```

i get this url :

```
localhost:8080/coders_ring/project/test/1.html
```

real url is :

```
localhost:8080/coders_ring/showProject.php?id=1
```

also i test in get url css file like this but not solution :

```
<link href="style/master_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/style/master_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

any body have a solution to load css and image file with this url rewriting ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a base href tag in your showproject.php file

Add this

```
<base href="http://localhost/coders_ring/" />
```